# Performing 3D vector editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I've searched the manuals and plugins and done some tests..

Is it in any way possible to perform 3D drawing and editing of vector objects for 3D mapping e.g. in a 3D shapefile or PostGIS 3D table?

Comment: To what extent do you need to edit an object: translocate, modify verticies, intersect / join, create from scratch?  What type of 3D objects to you have: are they just linear features with an M/Z value?

Comment: That would be a nice theme for a plugin: put a Blender viewport inside qgis, or a qgis layer in Blender (www.blender.org). That shouldn't be hard since both have python APIs.

Comment: @Pablo - theoretically a good idea but you would need to be careful of your versions because the current version of Blender uses Python 3.2 and the current version of QGIS uses Python 2.5.  What I do is to import the GDAL libraries into Blender.  You could get the QGIS functionality by runnning python 2.7 Subprocesses I suppose but that is starting to get messy.  Let's hope QGIS becomes compatible with Python 3.2 soon :)

Answer (score 2):

No, currently QGIS editing tools only handle the 2D case.

I'm not sure going the "Blender way" as mentioned in the comments will be an option - but that's really a topic for the developer mailing list.