# Digitizing Airport approach-zone with z information in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I'm trying to create a vector layer in QGIS out of this Z-dimensioned approach-zone for an ongoing multi-criteria analysis:

[image: Airport approach-zone]
* The oval shaped base should be 59,56 meters high (Z)

- For every "ring" z-value should be increased by 10 meters, ending
  at 159,56 meters (Z)
- The cone shaped things are flat plane 163/164 meters up until the 130
  meter mark, then drops until it reaches 59.56.

Could anyone with more experience with QGIS-digitizing with z-values point out a direction?

What painting tools to use? Right now I'm manually painting them, but results looks horrible and edgy.

note: I've already geo-referenced the above image.

Comment: Have you tried smoothing tools? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/generalizer/

Comment: Could you do [Raster to Vector](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html) to get the boundaries than edit the Z values into them?

Comment: The generalizer was nice, although still a lot of work.

Comment: It was imposible to get the boundaries from the Raster to Vector conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Last I check QGIS does not allow for Z editing. See the response to this older question: 
[Is it possible to perform 3D vector editing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/is-it-possible-to-perform-3d-vector-editing-in-qgis)

Comment: I was hoping things had changed since Underdark asked that question 4 years ago? And I've managed to at least draw the flat base plane on 59,56 meters (Z-value) and project it with Qgis2three to see that it actually "hangs" in the air. Now I'm just trying to find the best practice for digitizing it..